# PUT request sending params via URL

Tags: angularjs, http, parameters, put, angular-resource

I have a order resource that looks like so.

```
.factory('Order', order)

order.$inject = ['$resource', "ApiEndpoint"];

function order($resource, ApiEndpoint) {
  return $resource(ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders.json', {}, {
    create: {method: 'POST', url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders.json'},
    update: {method: 'PUT'},
    edit: {method: 'GET', url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders/edit.json'},
    remove_item: {method: 'GET', url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders/remove_item.json'},
  });
}
```

When I run `Order.update` like so

```
var params = {
  order: {
    line_items_attributes: {0: {quantity: 2, id: 1}}
  },
  order_id: 3
};

Order.update(params, function (resp, respHeaders) {
  console.log("response headers", respHeaders());
  console.log("change quantity resp", resp);
})
```

I also tried this:

```
Order.update({}, params, function (resp, respHeaders) {
  console.log("response headers", respHeaders());
  console.log("change quantity resp", resp);
})
```

The params sent to the server end up being inside the URL. For example this was one of the urls the server received

```
path="/api/mobile/orders.json?order=%7B%22line_items_attributes%22:%7B%220%22:%7B%22quantity%22:8,%22id%22:356265%7D%7D%7D"
```

I should also note that the method being received by the server is an `OPTIONS` request. The server has been set up to handle this.

Since I'm sending a PUT request why is `$resource` delivering the params via the URL and not part of the payload?

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])

the payload is the second argument, so try with this code

```
var params = {
  order: {
    line_items_attributes: {0: {quantity: 2, id: 1}}
  },
  order_id: 3
};

Order.update({}, params, function (resp, respHeaders) {
  console.log("response headers", respHeaders());
  console.log("change quantity resp", resp);
})
```

just add an empty object as first parameter to the update method.

have also a look to he section related to [custom put requests](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#creating-a-custom-put-request)

Comment: I tried this and the params are still being loaded into the URL.

Comment: the call to OPTIONS should be caused by [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), is your api endpoint on a different domain than the angular app?

Comment: Yes it is. I believe in the past we corrected this issue as we were making a POST request in the past and the POST request does not pass params into the url like the PUT request does.

Comment: the issue is not with PUT method but with CORS, have a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXKWwN), if you see the put call you'll see the parameters passed into the body of the request

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating an order then you should speficy the order id so that service can now which order is going to be updated

```
function order($resource, ApiEndpoint) {
  return $resource(ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders.json/:orderid', {}, {
    create: {method: 'POST', url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders.json'},
    update: {method: 'PUT',params : {orderid : '@order_id'},
    edit: {method: 'GET', url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders/edit.json'},
    remove_item: {method: 'GET', url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders/remove_item.json'},
  });
}
```

and then your call

```
Order.update(params, function (resp, respHeaders) {
  console.log("response headers", respHeaders());
  console.log("change quantity resp", resp);
})
```

Comment: Sorry but the params are still being passed via the URL.